# R How to get total CPU time with foreach?

Tags: r, time, parallel-foreach, cpu-time

I am trying to get total CPU hours of a code run in parallel (using `foreach` from the package `doParallel`) but I'm not sure how to go about doing this. I have used `proc.time()` but it just returns a difference in 'real' time. From what I have read of `system.time()`, it should also just do the same as `proc.time()`. How do I get total CPU hours of an R code run in parallel?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A Little trick is to return the measured runtime with your computation result together by `list`. An example as below, we use `system.time()` to get the runtime as same as `proc.time()`.

NOTE: this is the modified example from my blog post of [R with Parallel Computing from User Perspectives](http://www.parallelr.com/r-with-parallel-computing/).

```
# fake code to show how to get runtime of each process in foreach
library(foreach)
library(doParallel)

# Real physical cores in my computer
cores <- detectCores(logical = FALSE)
cl <- makeCluster(cores)
registerDoParallel(cl, cores=cores)


system.time(
  res.gather <- foreach(i=1:cores, .combine='list') %dopar%
  {  
    s.time <- system.time( {
    set.seed(i)
    res <- matrix(runif(10^6), nrow=1000, ncol=1000)
    res <- exp(sqrt(res)*sqrt(res^3))
    })
    list(result=res, runtime=s.time)
  }
)


stopImplicitCluster()
stopCluster(cl)
```

Thus, the runtime is saved in `res.gather` and you can get it easily. So, add them up and we can know how many total time for your parallel program.

```
> res.gather[[1]]$runtime
   user  system elapsed 
   0.42    0.04    0.48 
> res.gather[[2]]$runtime
   user  system elapsed 
   0.42    0.03    0.47 
> res.gather[[2]]$runtime[3] + res.gather[[2]]$runtime[3]
elapsed 
   0.94
```

Finally, the runtime of 2 R sessions is 0.94 sec without accounting wait time of R master.